# Prevent workflow field column from being added

Tags: 2010, workflow

I've got a few lines of code which programmatically add a workflow to a list content type. This works ok, but it also automatically adds a column to the default view of this list. I don't want that to happen, but I cannot find a way to prevent it. Of course I can retrieve the view again and delete the newly added column, but that seems a bit foolish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SPWorkflowTemplate and SPWorkflowAssociation has an option for StatusColumn.

"True to display a status column for workflow instances based on this workflow template in the user interface."

"True to display a status column for this workflow association in the user interface."

Try setting it to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowtemplate.statuscolumn.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociation.statuscolumn.aspx

Haven't tested it.

Comment: SPWorkflowAssociation.StatusColumn is readonly. But if you set SPWorkflowTemplate.StatusColumn to false and pass it to the SPWorkflowAssociation constructor, then the association's StatusColumn will be false.

Comment: Can someone please add a code example? I have the same requirement and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work when creating an association, you can edit the template to set the StatusColumn to false at the point of setting the association, but you cannot edit this after the association is created.

Thanks for this info, it led me to the answer as well!!