# Prevent Workflow Status Column From Being Added To Default View (CSOM)

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm using CSOM, when I publish workflow I have got additional workflow column in my default view. 
I found [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22049/prevent-workflow-field-column-from-being-added), but answer is not suits for CSOM.

Can anyone advise what need to do to to prevent the addition of a workflow status column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider the following approach, in particular remove the specified column explicitly once the workflow is published:

```
//The remaining code is omitted for clarity...

//Create the Association
workflowSubSvc.PublishSubscriptionForList(worklowSub, targetList.Id);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();


//Remove workflow status field from default view
var workflowField = targetList.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(worklowSub.Name);
ctx.Load(workflowField);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var view = targetList.DefaultView;
view.ViewFields.Remove(workflowField.InternalName);
view.Update();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```